# error 404: ressource (.jsp file) not available

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I am trying to create a web application with eclipse JAVA EE IDE. It consists in a form where the customer enters his contact details( name, first name, telephone email). When you click "enter" the application display the details and an error message if you have forgot to fill a field. When I click on validate("valider"), I gate the following message:

Etat HTTP 404 - /tp1/ afficherClient.jsp
type Rapport d''état
message /tp1/ afficherClient.jsp
ressource requested not available

**here is my web.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>tp1</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>Servlet de création du client</description>    
    <servlet-name>CreationClient</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.zdzee.tp.servlets.CreationClient</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CreationClient</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/creationClient</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**My servlets CreationClient:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.sdzee.tp.beans.Client;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CreationClient
 */
@WebServlet("/CreationClient")
public class CreationClient extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CreationClient() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());


    String nomClient =  request.getParameter("nomClient");
    String prenomClient =  request.getParameter("prenomClient");
    String telephoneClient =  request.getParameter("telephoneClient");
    String emailClient =  request.getParameter("emailClient");
    String adresseClient = request.getParameter( "adresseClient" );

    String message;

    if ( nomClient.trim().isEmpty() || adresseClient.trim().isEmpty() || telephoneClient.trim().isEmpty() ) {
        message = "Erreur - Vous n'avez pas rempli tous les champs obligatoires. <br> <a href=\"creerClient.jsp\">Cliquez ici</a> pour accéder au formulaire de création d'un client.";
    } else {
        message = "Client créé avec succès !";
    }
    Client client=new Client();
    client.setEmail(emailClient);
    client.setNom(nomClient);
    client.setPrenom(prenomClient);
    client.setTelephone(telephoneClient);
    client.setAdresse( adresseClient );

    request.setAttribute( "client", client );
    request.setAttribute( "message", message );

    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/ afficherClient.jsp" ).forward( request, response );

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

**My .jsp file which generate the form creerClient.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Création d'un client</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="inc/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="get" action="creationClient">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Informations client</legend>

                    <label for="nomClient">Nom <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="nomClient" name="nomClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="prenomClient">Prénom </label>
                    <input type="text" id="prenomClient" name="prenomClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="adresseClient">Adresse de livraison <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="adresseClient" name="adresseClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="telephoneClient">Numéro de téléphone <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="telephoneClient" name="telephoneClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="emailClient">Adresse email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailClient" name="emailClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="60" />
                    <br />
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" value="Valider"  />
                <input type="reset" value="Remettre à zéro" /> <br />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My jsp file which display the details afficherClient.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8" />
<title>Affichage d'un client</title>
</head>
<body>
        <%-- Affichage de la chaîne "message" transmise par la servlet --%>
        <p class="info">${ message }</p>
        <%-- Puis affichage des données enregistrées dans le bean "client" transmis par la servlet --%>
        <p>Nom : ${ client.nomClient }</p>
        <p>Prénom : ${ client.prenomClient }</p>
        <p>Adresse : ${ client.adresseClient }</p>
        <p>Numéro de téléphone : ${ client.telephoneClient }</p>
        <p>Email : ${ client.emailClient }</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**My bean Client.java:**

package com.sdzee.tp.beans;

```
public class Client {

private String nomClient;
private String prenomClient;
private String adresseClient;
private String telephoneClient;
private String  emailClient;

    public String getAdresse() {
        return this.adresseClient;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return this.nomClient;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return this.prenomClient;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return this.telephoneClient;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.emailClient;
    }

    public void setAdresse( String adresse ) {
        this.adresseClient = adresse;
    }

    public void setNom( String nom ) {
        this.nomClient = nom;
    }

    public void setPrenom( String prenom ) {
        this.prenomClient = prenom;
    }

    public void setTelephone( String telephone ) {
        this.telephoneClient = telephone;
    }
    public void setEmail( String email ) {
        this.emailClient = email;
    }       

}
```

[Here is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmaca.png)

Comment: what is the url before submitting the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [servlet API 3.0](https://javabeat.net/new-features-in-servlets-3-0/). So you don't need to specify in your web.xml file the servlet mapping. It is already mapped as an annotation in your Servlet. `@WebServlet("/CreationClient")`

Remove the servlet mapping from your web.xml so it looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>tp1</display-name>

    </web-app>
```

And in your .jsp file you need to make sure that your action attribute in your form matches the url mapping for your servlet

this is wrong:

```
 <form method="get" action="creationClient">
```

it needs to be this:

```
 <form method="get" action="CreationClient">
```

Because in your servlet you have mapped it here `@WebServlet("/CreationClient")`:

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class CreationClient
 */
@WebServlet("/CreationClient") //<----- this is your servlet URL
public class CreationClient extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

**Update**, in response to your propertynotfound error: change your Client class to this:

```
public class Client {

    String nom;
    String prenom;
    String adresse;
    String telephone;
    String  email;

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }
    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }
    public String getAdresse() {
        return adresse;
    }
    public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }
    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }
    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Now this is important, whenever you call these variables in your jsp you need to make sure that it matches what you named them, so :

```
String nom;
String prenom;
String adresse;
String telephone;
String  email;
```

Then you can call it like this in your jsp:

```
${client.nom}
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I have got an error message : "Launching Tomcat V7.0 Server at localhost(3)" has encountered a problem.Several ports(8005,8080,8009) required byTomcat v7.0 Server atlocalhost(3) are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this qserveryou will need to stop the other process or change the port number.

Comment: Yeah that happens. It's because   you have a background process still running on your server port. You need to either create a new server with a new port or kill the process that is running on that port in the background  with task manager. It will be a java process. Let me know what happens

Comment: When I click on "valider" on my form, I get the following message: Etat HTTP 500 - javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'nomClient' not found on type com.sdzee.tp.beans.Client. Even if the property 'nomClient' exists in my bean "Client". I ran the file "creerClient.jsp"

Comment: well this is different problem now, something to do with your bean. "nomClient" isn't set. But your servlet works now correct? When you click on the valider for your form, it reaches your servlet.

Comment: Certainly. But "nomClient" is set in my Servlet "CreationClient".Where do you think the problem is ?

Comment: Look at your Client object class. You are not setting "nomClient". Do you see how all the other variables have setters and getters, well nomClient doesn't have it. So when you call that variable in your jsp, you get the error, because it is not found.

Comment: I updated my answer to help you understand your new problem some more, check out my updated answer, let me know if that helps. Post the code of your jsp where the error is coming from if it doesn't help.

Comment: Yes I do set nomClient:    public void setNom( String nom ) {
        this.nomClient = nom;
    }
Just after setAdresse. I do get it :    public String getNom() {
        return this.nomClient;
    }
Just after getAdresse

Comment: No, you are not. You are calling "nomClient", but you have only set it as "nom". If you change it to "nom" it should work. If not, look at my updated answer and change your code so it is less confusing.